# Avoid creating too many custom objects

Tags: javascript, performance, object, types

Suppose I have a class called `Square`, which its constructor has two parameters: `position` and `size`, the former accepting a `Point` type, and the latter a `Size` type.

```
class Square {
    constructor (position, size) {
        this.position = position;
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

Every single time I call the `Square` constructor, will I need to create two objects just for passing them as arguments?

```
let mySquare = new Square(new Point(100, 100), new Size(200, 200));
```

Is this approach poorly performant? What can I do to avoid creating too many objects while not sacrificing code clarity?

I don't want to replace those custom types by `Square(x, y, width, height)`.

Comment: If `Square(x, y, with, height)` isn't an option, what do you expect to get for an answer? With as little background info as we have, we can hardly tell you anything other than: _"Performance should be fine."_

Comment: @Cerbrus then you should write an answer saying that there's nothing that can be done. Not every question can have the answer the OP always wanted, which should be fine.

Comment: In cases where the objects being passed in are immutable you can reuse them (such that multiple instances of `Square` have references to the same instance of `Size`).

Comment: @TiagoMarinho when is about performance, you could consider perform testing and benchmark your code and comparing.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Keeping track of the `Size`s can take more memory than just creating new ones per `Square`, though.

Comment: I'm asking that because I thought that there could be something being made wrong from my part, since I have never written such high-level code before (using a `Point` object instead of `x, y`), and since I'm not a skilled programmer as many of you are, there could be a language feature I'd be missing. If I'm doing it the right way, just tell me.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Yeah, but if you needed to create ten squares that are all the same size you could easily reuse a single `Size` object within a loop. It really depends on what the real use-cases might be in any given project. If the child objects in question can't be immutable you obviously can't reuse them at all. There's no one best approach.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho: What you're doing seems fine, to me.

Comment: hey i've not used javascript for a while but...is this really javascript?

Comment: @lelloman It's JavaScript ES6 (2015).

Comment: wohooo this looks cool xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance should be fine.

Even if you were to use something like `Square(x, y, with, height)`, you'd still be creating a `Point` and a `Size` in the `Square`'s constructor.

Comment: *"you'd still be creating a Point and a Size in the Square's constructor."* - Not if all are stored in separate properties. (Which is one possibility, just not want the OP wants to do.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: True, but then there'd be no reason not to use `Square(x, y, with, height)` :-)